# system.invalidoperationexception vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I make a program using vb.net in visual studio 2012.

This program to kill process another application in list.

but when i run it i have problem like this 
http://prntscr.com/80iqfd

My code :

```
    Dim Process8() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("RiPE")
    For Each MyKill As Process In Process8
        MyKill.Kill()
        Me.Hide()
        Logs()
    Next
    Dim Process9() As Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcessesByName("WPE PRO")
    For Each MyKill As Process In myProcess
        MyKill.Kill()
        Me.Hide()
        Logs()
    Next
```

anyone can help me to solve my program?
sorry for my bad english

Comment: You should put your `MyKill.Kill()` statements in Try Catch blocks because the process may exit between the time you got the reference and you actually kill it.

Comment: Look at your second for loop. Instead of using `myProcess` i think you want to use `Process9`...